# How can I find the first clusters/blocks of a file?

Tags: hex, filesystems, fat16

I have a FAT16 drive that contains the following info:
[image]
Bytes per sector: 512 bytes (0x200)

Sectors per cluster: 64 (0x40)

Reserved sectors: 6 (0x06)

Number of FATs: 2 (0x02)

Number of root entries: 512 (0x0200)

Total number of sectors: 3805043 (0x3a0f73)

Sectors per file allocation table: 233 (0xE9)

Root directory is located at sector 472 (0x1d8)
[image]

I'm looking for a file with the following details:

File name: LOREMI~1

File extension: TXT

File size: 3284 bytes (0x0cd4)

First cluster: 660 (0x294)

However, I would admit that the start of the file cluster is located at sector 42616. My problem is that what equation should I use that would produce 42616?
[image]

I have trouble figuring this out since there is barely any information about this other than a tutorial made by Tavi Systems but the part involving this is very hard to follow.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the FAT filesystem is fairly well documented. The official FAT documentation by Microsoft can be found by the filename [fatgen103](https://download.microsoft.com/download/0/8/4/084c452b-b772-4fe5-89bb-a0cbf082286a/fatgen103.doc).

The directory entry `LOREMI~1.TXT` can be found in the root directory and is precedented by the long file name entry (`xt`, `lorem ipsum.t` → `lorem ipsum.txt`), the directory entry is documented in the «FAT Directory Structure» chapter; in case of FAT16 you are interested in the 26th to 28th byte to get the *cluster address* (`DIR_FstClusLo`), which is (little endian!) `0x0294` (or 660₁₀).

Based on the BPB header information you provided we can calculate the the data sector like this:

```
data_sector = (cluster-2) * sectors_per_cluster + 
              (reserved_sectors + (number_of_fats * fat_size) +
               first_data_sector)
```

Why `cluster-2`? Because the first two clusters in a FAT filesystem are always reserved for the BPB header block as well as the FAT itself, see chapter «FAT Data Structure» in `fatgen103.doc`.

In order for us to solve this, we still need to determine the sector span of the root directory entry. For FAT12/16 this can be determined like this:

```
first_data_sector = ((root_entries * directory_entry_size) +
                     (bytes_per_sector - 1)) // bytes_per_sector
```

The directory entry size is always 32 bytes as per specification (see chapter «FAT Directory Structure» in `fatgen103.doc`), every other value is known by now:

```
first_data_sector = ((512*32)+(512-1)) // 512 → 32
data_sector = (660-2)*64+(6+(2*233)+32) → 42616
```